# Can't set up Tomcat 8.5 server in Eclipse for an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Java Servlet

Tags: eclipse, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been developing an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Java Servlet with Eclipse successfully for a while. However when I log onto the AWS console it tells me that the Tomcat 8 Java 8 platform is deprecated. I have updated the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse and Tomcat 8 Java 8 is the latest it supports. While I can set up a Tomcat 8.5 Java 8 platform manually using the AWS console, I cannot do so using the AWS Toolkit in Eclipse, I cannot set up a server in Eclipse for a Tomcat 8.5 Java 8 Elastic Beanstalk application either.

Are there AWS Toolkit config files that I can edit to achieve what I need?